# set left,right,bottom,top padding and margin in the expression blend properties window all at once

Tags: expression-blend

I could have sworn I've seen a video showing how to set the padding for an element for the left,right,bottom,top all at once with a keyboard shortcut to a single value but I can't find it or remember how. So how do I set the padding for an element to "5" for all sides at once in the property window?

The resulting xaml should be:

```
 Padding="5"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the right side of the properties there should be a small box. Hovering mouse reveals tooltip saying **"Advanced options"**. Click on it and a menu will appear. Choose **"Custom Expressions..."** and enter a single value. The value will be applied to all sides of property

<del>I don't have enough reputation to post image, but</del> here's a screeenshot
[image: Blend Thickness Property Advanced Options]

Actually, anything entered will be written to the XAML as-is. For example entering **5,2** would set the left and right padding to **5** with top and bottom padding to **2**. The XAML result is `padding="5,2"`. It is possible to enter **{Binding}** and other expression as well.

[Personal Rant]
*I found this after being frustrated by Blend by just how unobvious it is to set all sides of thickness-type property (i believe the type of margin, padding, etc is called thickness) at once, even thought it should be common action. It doesn't involve keyboard shortcut, but i believe it's an acceptable solution for the problem (setting all sides of thickness property). And although my answer is late, i hope it help someone in the future*

Comment: You now have enough reputation to post images—go crazy!

Comment: The [Privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges) page lets you track what you unlock as you get more points—you only need 10 points to post images.